# Error: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE when Deploying to IIS Server from Azure Pipeline

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, file-in-use

I am encountering an issue when attempting to deploy my application to an IIS server from an Azure Pipeline. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

Error Code: **ERROR_FILE_IN_USE**
More Information: Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'file.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process. In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications.

[image]

I have tried several solutions to resolve this error, but none of them have worked so far. Here are the steps I've taken:

1)Enabled the "**Take App Offline**" option.
2)Attempted to **stop** the application deployment and then **start** the application.
3)Tried **copying the files** to the destination .
4)**Deleted** the **web.config** file from the source and then attempted to deploy.
5)Increased the **retry count** for the Deploy task.
6)Add these lines in csproj of project :

< EnableMSDeployAppOffline >true< /EnableMSDeployAppOffline >
< GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies >true< /GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>

Despite trying these solutions, I continue to encounter the same "**ERROR_FILE_IN_USE**" error. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: try to recycle application pool before deploying code. or use tool like procmon to check which process is using the file.

Comment: I think setting the `appOffline` rule and `EnableMSDeployAppOffline` property [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/deployment-migration/web-deploy-error-codes#error_file_in_use) was the correct action to take. However, you need to successfully deploy the app with those changes. You may have to stop the app, deploy, then start the app again.

Comment: I have already added this property and set tasks as you described Stop , Deploy , Start app but still it have same response 
do we have any other solution other than recycle application pool ?

Comment: @TahamiRizwan you could consider doing a clean deployment, deleting all files in the destination directory (ensuring backups first) and then deploying the new files. if it still does not work you can use procmon or other tool to find which process is using the file.

Comment: I have check through process monitor file is locked by that API in which we are deploying

Comment: @TahamiRizwan could you try adding  <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost> in the .csproj this will help enabling  Shadow copying and you should be able to deploy updated DLLs without stopping the application pool. or else only option left is stopping iis app pool or recycle it.  while using the stopping iis site have you tried to kill the task and tried to deploy the code?

Comment: added <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost> in the .csproj but again got with the same error